# why does ASM methodnode.signature return null?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

why does ASM methodnode.signature return null ?
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Test.class");
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(fis);
        ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
        cr.accept(cn, 0);
        List<MethodNode> methods = cn.methods;
        for (MethodNode methodNode : methods) {
            System.out.println(methodNode.signature);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `signature` to return?

Comment: The method signature!

Comment: Where are you using it for? I'm not sure if this field is always available. The javadoc says :"The method's signature. May be null."
A signature never is null, so it's a bit confusing. `name+desc` is the closest to the method signature I think.

Comment: @jvwilge Actually am trying to do some reverse engineering kind of thing...! i want to reconstruct the original java file from the class file..!.Am not able to find any proper documentation for ASM

Answer (score 1):

The signature is null to indicate that there is no generic information for this method. The signature is nothing than meta data and ignored by the Java runtime which rather looks at a method's descriptor which must never be null.

Comment: why is there no generic info?? Actually there are many more fields like local variable list which also return null. ASM APIs have mysterious behaviour.It will be helpful if you could provide me any link with proper documentation.

Comment: This is related to the representation within the Java class file. Generic signatures are merely meta data that can be present since Java 5. If the value is null, then the information is not placed in the class file either. ASM is fairly close to the class file representation, thus this low level analogy.

Comment: @Aravind Ram: it shouldn’t be so hard to find [the ASM documentation](http://asm.ow2.org/) or [the JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html). There is nothing mysterious here.